# ComponentWillReceiveProps is not called when we navigate between stack navigator components?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

```
export default (DrawNav = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: { screen: Home },
    QuestionDetail: { screen: QuestionDetail },
    QuestionAsk: { screen: QuestionAsk }
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Home",
    headerMode: "none"
  }
));
```

Home component lists questions and QuestionDetail shows detail information of the questions but here is the problem that i faced, whenever you back to home from QuestionDetail or other component i want to grab the questions and here is what i did in Home component,

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.getQuestions();
}

componentWillReceiveProps() {
    this.setState({ questions: [] }, () => {
        this.getQuestions();
    });
}

getQuestions() {
    this.setState({ isLoading: true });
    axios.get(`http://${IP_ADDRESS}/api/questions`)
        .then(response => {
            console.log('response data: ', response.data);
            this.setState({ questions: response.data, isLoading: false })
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            this.setState({ isLoading: false });
            console.log('QUESTIONS ERR: '+err);
            // this.props.history.push('/');
        })
}
```

but componentWillReceiveProps is not called when you navigate from QuestionDetail to Home?

Answer (score 1):

`componentWillReceiveProps` is triggered only when component prop updates and not on initial render. As [the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops) states,

> React doesn’t call UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps() with initial props during mounting. It only calls this method if some of component’s props may update. Calling this.setState() generally doesn’t trigger UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps().

`componentWillReceiveProps` is deprecated, particularly because it's often misused. For asynchronous actions `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate` are supposed to be used instead of `componentWillMount` and `componentWillReceiveProps`:

> If you need to perform a side effect (for example, data fetching or an animation) in response to a change in props, use componentDidUpdate lifecycle instead.

If same logic is applicable to both hooks, there should be a method to reuse. There's already such method, `getQuestions`:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.getQuestions();
}

componentDidUpdate() {
    this.getQuestions();
}

getQuestions() {
    this.setState({ isLoading: true, questions: [] });

    axios.get(`http://${IP_ADDRESS}/api/questions`)
    ...
}
```

Comment: Also, `static getDerivedStateFromProps` if you want to derive some state from new props without rendering first.

Comment: example: (excuse the bad formatting in comments)
```static getDerivedStateFromProps (props, state) {
  if (props.drawerOpen !== state.drawerOpen || props.width !== state.width) {
    return {
      drawerOpen: props.drawerOpen,
      width: props.width,
      landscape: getLandscape(props)
    }
  } else return null
}
```

Comment: @ThaJay I believe getDerivedStateFromProps is not really applicable here because this isn't a place for side effects (async request is a side effect), also it couldn't get access to this.getQuestions,

Comment: @HenokTesfaye It's unclear from the question how often it's expected to be called. But updates should be controlled with shouldComponentUpdate or PureComponent.

Comment: Yeah @estus but it is not recommended to call setState inside componentDidUpdate.

Comment: @HenokTesfaye I see what you mean with 'componentDidUpdate is called many times'. I guess you've got recursive state updates. *it is not recommended to call setState inside componentDidUpdate.* - there's no such recommendation. It's ok to call setState there. You just need to prevent recursive state updates. This is what *But updates should be controlled with shouldComponentUpdate or PureComponent* is about. Which updates should make `getQuestions` run? Are there problems with using PureComponent?

Comment: @estus, you are correct, getQuestions needs acces to `this`. If it would just set state it could also return state but it's definitely a asynchronous non pure function.

Comment: @estus, yes it's okay to call setState once from `componentDidUpdate` and another time asynchronous, but then it's better to pass a state setter function from the parent as a prop and use that to give the child component new props. Code can stay cleaner that way and functions can be more pure.

Comment: @ThaJay I agree, lifting the state up is one of ways this case could be addressed, possibly the preferable one.